# Get URL source quick in Android

Tags: java, android, download, fileinputstream

i am used to download URL HTML source in Java using InputStream and readLine() method. This seems to be very slow when page has a lot of EOLs.
My current approach to download is by using java.nio library.

```
URL website = new URL("url.tothe.site.com/page.html");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("temp.html",0);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

But moving to Android, the transferFrom() method fails, giving this message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: position=0 count=9223372036854775807
        at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:372)
```

...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try using a lower value for the third parameter to `transferFrom()`, rather than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Because there are several libraries available to you depending on what you want to do next. For instance, if you want to traverse or parse the content of the HTML i would suggest using JSoup: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't know how could I miss such a simple error, it only requires looking to the transferFrom() API doc.